# Cannot change resolution in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, resolution

I have an ASUS ROG STRIX with AMD Ryzen9, Nvidia Geforce RTX 4060, kernel 6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1; I am using the NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535 (proprietary,tested). The default resolution is 2560x1440 (16:9) but with this resolution everything is too small, and I would like to change to 1920x1080. I changed the resolution months ago and it worked, but some days ago I turned on the pc and the screen looked like this:

[image]

After a while I managed to figure out that the only way to see the screen again was to set it to the default resolution.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Please ask here instead: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thank you, that forum helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me, as described [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cannot-change-resolution-in-ubuntu-22-04/279659/2), was to upgrade to kernel 6.7 using liquorix ppa and not mainline repo:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damentz/liquorix -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-image-liquorix-amd64
reboot
```

I also updated drivers to nvidia-driver-545...I am not really sure if this update is necessary, but in case the above commands are not enough give it a try. 
Hope this may be helpful for someone else